# Use VB.NET to get a filtered list Wordpress posts?

Tags: vb.net, wordpress, xml-rpc

This is the code I have so far, but I can not understand why I am getting this error (Error 400).

I think that the problem is in the formatting of the argument filter. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
Imports CookComputing.XmlRpc

Public Class Form2

    <XmlRpcUrl("http://example.wordpress.org/xmlrpc.php")> _
    Public Interface IWP
        Inherits IXmlRpcProxy

        <XmlRpcMethod("wp.getPosts")> _
        Function getPosts(ByVal args() As String) As Post()

    End Interface

    Public Structure Post
        Public post_id As String
        Public post_title As String
        Public post_type As String
        '...
    End Structure

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim proxy As IWP = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(Of IWP)()
        Dim args() As String = {"blog_id", "user", "password", "post_type='page'"}
        Dim posts() As Post
        Try
            posts = proxy.getPosts(args)
            For Each post In posts
                ListBox1.Items.Add(post.post_title)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Dont you have to end your function also?

Comment: What is the function?

Comment: <XmlRpcMethod("wp.getPosts")> _
        Function getPosts(ByVal args() As String) As Post()

Comment: That is correct. The problem I think is in the array {"blog_id", "user", "password", "post_type = 'page'"}

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: "Server returned a fault exception: [403] The type of item specified is invalid"

Comment: That means you dont have proper access to the request. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403 , make sure you have proper access to the resource.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Woller, according to the error message it is :) But can it be one of your values passed are wrong? the single quotes in the post_type='page'?

Comment: Probably the syntax is this: {"blog_id", "user", "password", {"post_type", "page"}}. An array within another array. But in vb.net I do not know how to do it :(

Comment: {"blog_id", "user", "password", New String() {"post_type", "page"}}

Comment: I tried but it does not work. This is the reference page where are indicated the parameters send: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.getPosts

Comment: The last one is optional, try it without to see if it works to determine that this is in fact the problem

Comment: I tried it without filter and it works. It returns a structure with all the posts. The problem occurs only when sending the filter parameters.

Comment: Have you just tried this then? Dim args() As String = {"blog_id", "user", "password", "post_type"}

Comment: According to the documentation user parameter should not work but username. Do you have user or username?

Comment: The name of the username parameter not send, sending only the content

Comment: I must be getting tired :) that was a stupid question haha.

Comment: often happens to me when I'm tired :)

Comment: I found some variable names on this page http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.getPost maybe these are the correct namings?

Comment: You've seen them. In the posted code, I have created a prototype of a structure called the Post. This includes some members appointed as indicated on the page that I've reported. If I run a post request without filtering members at Post are populated by data.
Sorry for my English. I do help from google translate.